# Questions about regular expressions

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I have a few questions about regular expressions. From what I see you could only use * for number of letter but if I want to write L={a^n b^n|n>=0} how would I show in a regular expression that the number of letters is equal.

And in general how would I show any kind of relationship between the number of letters in a regular expression?

Comment: You can't. The language `L` you described is not regular, and it's easy to show this with the pumping lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages
Regular expressions are capable of checking parity (think modulo arithmetic) but not arbitrary substring length.

Comment: Thanks you are right. will a language L1={0^n 1^k | n mod 3=k mod 3} be regular then? I'm trying to find a regular expression for it but i'm not able to determine if it is even regular

Comment: Yes, that language is regular. You can express it like this: `(000)*(111)*|0(000)*1(111)*|00(000)*11(111)*`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was close to getting to this expression but didn't think about putting a letter 3 time inside the ()*

Answer (score 0):

You have hit on a really important idea in formal language theory - pure/theoretical regular expressions cannot match the language a^n b^n! This is an important result. The Myhill-Nerode theorem is a nice way to understand why this is the case but, basically, it boils down to this: if you can show that no finite automaton could accept the language, it's not regular and has no regular expression.

For your language in particular, suppose it is regular and there's a regular expression. We then know there is a deterministic finite automaton that accepts the language. We can further infer that there is a deterministic finite automaton with as few states as possible - a minimal DFA. Let the number of states in this DFA be p. Now, consider the string a^p b^p in our language. Because the number of states is p and the string length is greater than p-1, the DFA must have looped at some point in processing this string of length 2p. Let x be the substring of a^p b^p processed while traversing this loop. Then, since our DFA accepts a^p b^p, it must also accept any string obtained by traversing the loop any number of times, or by not traversing it at all. That is, we can get rid of the substring x, or change it to x^2 or x^k, and that string should be in our language, too. Is there a choice for x that works for us? As it turns out, there is not - no matter what substring of a^p b^p we select, changing the number of occurrences gives us a string not in our language (either it changes the number of a only, the number of b only, or the order of a and b in the middle). Therefore, our DFA does not exist and so there is no regular expression. This is basically a long-winded proof by the pumping lemma for regular languages, another tool.

The least capable (canonical) system of computation capable of describing the language a^n b^n is the class of context-free languages. Context-free grammars can be used to describe how these languages are generated. A CFG for your language is this:

```
S -> aSb
S -> epsilon
```

The way to use this is to start with S (a non-terminal start symbol) and then use productions (mapping rules) to derive intermediate expressions until you are left with a string of only terminal symbols (our terminal symbols are a and b). We can generate aaabbb like S -> aSb -> aaSbb -> aaaSbbb -> aaabbb.

Now, if you are asking about applied programming using "regex" libraries, these typically offer more functionality that allows non-regular languages to be captured. They've probably made those ungodly monstrosities Turing-equivalent, check GitHub for implementations of Quake built only on "regex".